# Where should I initialize select when using Materialize and Meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, materialize

I'm trying to use Materialize Forms on Meteor. On its Materialize's page it says I should init the "select" input field like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select();
});
```

I've tried calling this on Meteor.startup, Template.body.created - nothing worked. I get the following error:

> undefined is not a function (evaluating '$('select').material_select()')

Where should I initialize it?

Answer (score 5):

Use the template's `.rendered` [callback](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_rendered)

```
<template name="hello">
    <select><option>...</option></select>
</template>
```

Then you can have this in your js file

```
Template.hello.onRendered(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
});
```

The template is added to the body most likely after rendered has already fired so thats why the body rendered didn't work. If you use `.created` the DOM hasn't rendered yet.

Comment: That's great, but it fails when the select is rendered dynamically (i.e., not when the template is first loaded, but later).  In that case, this bit of code must be called *after* the select has been rendered... unless somebody has a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Akshat's answer is correct but if it still doesn't work for you, there might be a problem with subscription not fired yet or not every needed part of DOM beeing rendered. Use afterflush then.

```
Template.listing.onRendered(function () {
    var template = this;

    template.subscribe('listOfThings', function () {
    Tracker.afterFlush(function() {
       template.$('select').material_select();
    });
  });
});
```

Here is a conversation about that: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4401#issuecomment-103340262

And the docs: http://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-flush